# Dealing with a matrix representation of a linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Is the following statement true or false? If it is the former case, prove it. If it is the latter, give a counterexample.
>
> Let $n \in \aleph_0$ and $L:\Re^{n} \rightarrow \Re^{n}$ be an injective linear mapping. Let $A \in \Re^{n \times n}$ be an invertible matrix. Then there is a basis $\alpha$ of $\Re^{n}$ and a basis $\beta$ of $\Re^{n}$ such that $A = L_{\alpha}^{\beta}$
>
> **HINT:** Check whether $\bigl(
> \operatorname{Id}\bigr)_{\beta}^{\alpha} = L_{\alpha}^{\alpha}A^{-1}$ holds.

I know that to go from a vector with coordinates relative to a basis $\alpha$ to a vector with coordinates relative to a basis $\beta$ we can use the matrix representation of the identity transformation: $\bigl(\operatorname{Id}\bigr)_{\alpha}^{\beta}$.

I am approaching the problem through a diagram:

[image]

OK so we've obtained the equation

$$co_{\beta}(v) = \Big( Id \Big)_{\alpha}^{\beta} X = X'$$

So I think we can assert that $\bigl(\operatorname{Id}\bigr)_{\alpha}$ is the matrix representation of the linear transformation $A:X \rightarrow X'$

So $A$ should be

$$A = \bigl(\operatorname{Id}\bigr)_{\alpha}^{\beta}$$

Mmm but I guess that I cannot simply assert that

$$\bigl(\operatorname{Id}\bigr)_{\alpha} = L_{\alpha}^{\beta}$$

And state that the assertion is correct.

Besides I did not use the fact that $A$ is invertible (nor the hint).

So I must be missing something...

**EDIT:**

I see it takes some technical work to prove it. I am trying to play around with the formula's for change of base and trying to come up with "inverse" formulas for them, **but I am stuck.**

Any hint is very welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find bases $\langle e_i'\rangle$, $\langle e_i''\rangle$ such that
$$
e_i \cdot A e_j = e''_i \cdot L e_j'
$$

Since $L$ is injective
$$
e_i \cdot A e_j = e_i \cdot L^{-1} L  A e_j
$$

so the choice $e''_i = L^{-1 \dagger} e_i$ and $e'_i = A e_i$ works.

$A$ needs to be invertible, otherwise the definition of $e_i'$ doesn't qualify as a basis.